# Append ajax results

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to print data of my function below, so far i tried to put it in loop like `$.each(data.data, function(key, value) {`, also tried getting results directly like `data.price` or `data['price']` even `+ price +` nothing works, return `undefined`.

`script`

```
function myfunction(){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

      var cityname = $("#city option:selected").text();
          cityname = cityname.substring(cityname.indexOf("-")+2);
      var statename = $("#province option:selected").text();

      if(statename && cityname) {
          console.log(statename + " - " + cityname);
          $.ajax({ 
              url: '{{ url('getcityandstate') }}/' + statename + '/' + cityname,
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  // $('select[name="postchoose"]').append('<option id="postchoose" class="form-control" value="'+ price +'">'+ title +'</option>');
              }
          });
      }
  };
```

`results`

```
[…]
​
0: {…}
​​
cart_amount: null
​​
city: "Pandeglang"
​​
created_at: "2018-03-23 12:19:28"
​​
id: 6
​​
price: "20"
​​
state: "Banten"
​​
title: "gfgg"
​​
updated_at: "2018-03-23 12:24:47"
​​
__proto__: Object { … }
​
length: 1
​
__proto__: Array []
```

## Question

1. How to print my data?

## UPDATE

here is my controller

```
public function flatshippingcostincart(Request $request, $statename,$cityname) {
      $state = $request->statename;
      $city = $request->cityname;
      if($state != '' && $city != ''){
        $shipping = Shipping::where('state', '=', $state)->where('city', '=', $city)->get();
        return response()->json($shipping);
      }
    }
```

Comment: is data an array? in that case, `data[0].price`. if you're expecting more than one row, you should do a loop

Comment: @Jorg actually, i will validate my city and state name (selected by user) in controller and if have exact match will return result so i don't need to have loop, is only 1 result or true or false

Comment: the `0:` in that result copy / paste kind of implies an array but since it's just something that came from the console I can't be sure. Did `data[0]` have your object?

Comment: @Jorg yes it printed results.

Comment: The `__proto__: Array []` parts indicates `data` to be an `Array`, with `length` of 1. As Jorg said, you should use `data[0].price` to get the value.

Comment: @TKJohn so there is no way to avoid `[0]` ?

Comment: Since the `data` is returned from server, no. Server has determined the structure of `data`. If you can edit the codes of server, you can make it returns one `cityandstate` instance instead of `List<cityandstate>`

Comment: well i have access to database and controller if you mean that? what should i change? get my data as array? as json? etc.?

Comment: In the controller. I assume you are returning a `List` or an `Array` now.

Comment: @TKJohn I included my controll

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the server language you use. But I'm quite sure you may find another method instead of "`get()`", which will return exactly one result, not "all possible results" as `Array`.

Comment: @mafortis replace `->get()` with `->first()`, the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) say it brings back only one entry (if i guessed laravel correctly at least...)

Comment: @Jorg `[0]` in ajax does the same as `first()` difference is `[0]` order is `ASC` but `first()` is `desc`.